# C# Reflection - Base class static fields in Derived type

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, static, field

In C#, when I'm reflecting over a derived type, how come I don't see base classes' static fields?

I've tried both `type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static)` and `type.GetFields()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how it works. `static` members are really non-object-oriented stuff. They are not polymorphic and they really belong to their declaring type and are unrelated to other types in the inheritance hierarchy. For instance, a static initializer for a base class is not required to run before accessing a static member in a derived class.

`static` members of base classes are not returned unless `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` is specified:

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static 
             | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
             | BindingFlags.Public)
```

Comment: Should be noted that this still won't find *private* statics on a base class.  Just in case that's what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Yes, that was just an example. Just add `BindingFlags.NonPublic` in case you need it.

Comment: That still won't do it actually.  You have to reflect on private static fields directly on the base class.  Although I hope OP isn't trying to do that ;)

Comment: Quick question though. I tried BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy stuff to find methods and in this case it returns nothing. Why is that so?

Comment: You'll have to specify `BindingFlags.Public` too. Are there any public methods?

Comment: Yea they are all public. I specified BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy and nothing came up. Just a bit weird. If I specify no flags all public base/derived methods come up.

Comment: You need to specify `BindingFlags.Static` and/or `BindingFlags.Instance`.

Comment: I struggled with this a bit untill I realized that what I was trying to look up was a property...

Answer (score 6):

Because they belong to the base type, and are not inherited. Move up to that type, and you'll find them.

-- Edit

Mehrdad has the correct answer, but just for completeness:

```
foreach(FieldInfo f in b.GetType().GetFields(
    BindingFlags.Static
    | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
    | BindingFlags.Instance
    | BindingFlags.Public
    )){
    Console.WriteLine("found: " + f.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy enumeration to Static and this will also search static members. More information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your type is just your type - it doesn't include base types.  You'll need to use `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` if you want to search fields in base classes.

You should probably take a look at the [BindingFlags documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx) to accomplish what you need.