# How to get public static method of base class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

My base class has a public static method, but when I call `typeof(TDerived).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |BindingFlags.Static`) my method doesn't get returned. (TDerived of course inherits in some way from my base class). I don't have a reference to my base class at the place of this query.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can get hold of the base class of your own class through reflection though, use `typeof(TDerived).BaseType`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Reflection - Base class static fields in Derived type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325280/c-sharp-reflection-base-class-static-fields-in-derived-type)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` flag:

```
typeof(TDerived).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
```

It is a [documented behavior in the Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx) for `Type.GetMethods(BindingFlags)` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get hold of all the static members of your direct base type, ie. only the static methods of the class from which the current class inherits, then you can access it through reflection as well.

Your code, from your question, would then become:

```
typeof(TDerived).BaseType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                ^---+---^
                    |
                    +-- add this
```

Of course, this would *only* get the static methods of that type. If you want all the static methods of your own type *and* the base type(s), then go with the FlattenHierarchy option that [@Ondrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245183/ondrej-tucny) [answered with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675006/how-to-get-public-static-method-of-base-class/5675055#5675055), much better.