# How to get all members (including inherited members) of an INamedTypeSymbol in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Using the `GetMembers()` method of `INamedTypeSymbol` seems to return only types explicitly declared in that class.  How can I get a list of all the methods, including the inherited ones?

If this requires walking the chain of base classes, calling `GetMembers()` on each one, how can I determine which method is the "most derived" one, so to speak?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711500/c-sharp-reflection-get-info-for-all-members-of-class-and-base-classes) and possible duplicate question.

Comment: @rajasekhara I don't see how that's a duplicate, since it uses reflection, and not Roslyn, and also it's searching for a member of a particular name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this based on a particular location (so that things like accessibility are incorporated, then `SemanticModel.LookupSymbols` is what you need. If you want something else, then it isn't something the compiler deals with, so you'll have to put it together yourself using `GetMembers()`